# LMAX Disruptor with Kotlin: Can't use lambda?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, disruptor-pattern

For example in Java I can do this with LMAX disruptor:

`Disruptor<NetworkEvent> disruptor = new Disruptor<>(NetworkEvent::new, 2048, Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor());`

In Kotlin I try this equivalent:

`val disruptor = Disruptor<NetworkEvent>({ NetworkEvent() }, 2048, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())`

But I'm greeted with this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you dont need to specify T, kotlin can infer it.

Second the error message says whats wrong,
Disruptor wants a EventFactory, but you pass it a simple lambda.

If you want to pass a lambda as SAM Interface, sometimes its needed to preceed the lambda with the interface name.

Try the following (untested):

```
val disruptor = Disruptor(EventFactory { NetworkEvent()}, 2048,....)
```